# Shadow edges from object mode different from edit mode

Tags: shadows

[image]

Shadows are being smoothed around all vertices, like fake extra vertices exist around all real vertices. I don't want this (at least yet). This sort of happened to me, I must have misused some hotkey. Why is this behavior caused, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Do you have any modifiers on mesh (like **Bevel**) ?

Comment: at least intentionally, no.

Comment: You'd better check, that is exactly what it looks like

Comment: I've checked and that was the problem. I had never applied this before, didn't even know where to check. Thank you for your help|